# Multiple return statements in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to do multiple returns in MVC controller? I need to return the following:

```
return Content(pieChart.GetHtmlImageMap("gMap"));
return RedirectToAction("Chart", new { display = 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.  It looks like you may be using javascript?, in that case use one return statement and put multiple items into an array, i.e.:

return [Content(pieChart.GetHtmlImageMap("gMap")), RedirectToAction("Chart", new { display = 1 })];